# Show alert when ApplicationDidBecomeActive and redirect to another View if user choose Continue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, uialertview

I'm implementing an in-app purchase feature. In addition to Apple Store standard purchase flow, I have another receipt validation from my own server side. Sometimes, the purchase procedure is complete on Apple side and the app exist before my server validates the receipt.

So I store the receipt in NSUserDefaults. And whenever applicationDidBecomeActive, I would check if there's pending receipt in NSUserDefaults. If yes, I would like to pop up an alert, asking user whether to continue completing the purchase. If user canceled, then I would remove the receipt cancel the purchase. Otherwise, I would direct user to a purchase view, and do the rest of work.

Previously, I did the checking inside `AppDelegate ApplicationDidBecomeActive`. It seems not to be a good practice. I then try to move the code into MainViewController, catch `AppicationDidBecomeActive` notification in init. But I'm not sure what's the correct way of doing so? I try to catch the event with `selector:@selector(resumePurchase:)` and here's my resumePurchase code

```
- (void)resumePurchase:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *purchaseDocument = (NSData*)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"lastPurchaseDocument"];
    if (!purchaseDocument) {
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"You have an incomplete purchase in the app, do you want to continue the payment?",@"resume purchase.")];
        self.resumePurchaseAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Resume Payment",@"alter title")
                                                              message:message
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",@"Cancel caption")
                                                    otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Continue",@"altert approve button"), nil];
        [self.resumePurchaseAlert show];
    }
}
```

This seems ok so far. I'm stuck at the Continue button handler

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView == self.resumePurchaseAlert) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) { // Cancel
            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:kPurchaseDocument];
            [userDefaults synchronize];
        }
        if (buttonIndex == 1) { // Continue
            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSDictionary *purchaseDocument = (NSDictionary*)[userDefaults objectForKey:kPurchaseDocument];
            NSData *purchasedReceipt = [purchaseDocument objectForKey:kPurchasedReceipt];
            NSString *purchasedFeature = [purchaseDocument objectForKey:kPurchasedFeature];
            if (purchasedFeature && purchasedReceipt) {
                // here I want to redirect the view to PurchaseViewController
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how can I redirect the view to PurchaseViewController in an elegant way...

Answer (score 0):

in other `UIViewController` check value that you saved in `NSUserDefaults` and do nabvigation according to it.